# CSS Question - Slider Menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

The image slider menu items are shifted downward 5px on every page  the blog page, where they are positioned correctly. I can see the shift in Firebug but do not know where in CSS to fix.
http://drkateklemer.com 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in line 662 of your style.css for the organic natural summer theme. Change the margins to 0px, going from this:

```
#contenthome h1, #content h1 {
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: normal;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 32px;
    }
```

To this:

```
#contenthome h1, #content h1 {
        color: #333333;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: normal;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        line-height: 32px;
        }
```

Note: Tested using Developer Tools for Chrome.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this was the answer you were looking for, I'd be very happy if you marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

wordpress is loading the images into the content block, i dont think it your css just how images are accessed through your template

Answer (score 0):

```
#contenthome h1, #content h1 {
        color: #333333;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: normal;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        line-height: 32px;
    }
```